# Why is the gain of this amplifier so small?

Tags: circuit-analysis

Consider the following circuit:

[image: circuit]

I want to find the gain of this configuration, with and without the bypass capacitor (the 47uF capacitor).

Vx will be taken as the input voltage and Vout as the output.

**Part 1: using the bypass capacitor**

Using the small signal pi model, we obtain the following circuit.

[image: pi model equ circuit]

Therefore:

Vout = -(ro || 4.7k || 10k) * gm * Vin

Av = Vout / Vin = -(ro || 4.7k || 10k) * gm

I built this circuit and measured and found that the current through the drain is 1.8074 mA. This would give ro = VA/ID = 25/1.8074 = 13.86 ohms. If we consider gm to be equal to 0.5 * 10^(-3) Siemens and we calculate Av, we get -6.90 * 10^(-3) V/V.

Question:

Why is the gain so low?

**Part 2: without the bypass capacitor**

Using the T-model, we get the following circuit.

[image: t-model circuit]

Analyzing this circuit, we get:

Vout = - gm * Vgs * (4.7k || 10k)

Vin = (1/gm + 1k) * gm * Vgs

Therefore, Av = Vout/Vin = -1.067 after plugging in the values.

Question:
This gain makes more sense. Is this because ro was ignored in the T-model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your calculation, you have made an error.
It is correct that the gain is determined by ro||RD||Rload - however, in this expression the quantity ro is the **small-signal output resistance** of the FET (equivalent to the inverse slope of the Id=f(VDS) curves, normally in the higher kOhm range). Hence it is wrong to use the DC values for calculating ro (VA/ID, resulting in a very small value).

Comment: "equivalent to the inverse slope of the Id=f(VDS) curves, normally in the higher kOhm range" can you please elaborate on this? how would i calculate the output resistance? thanks so much! edit: is it by doing ro = vds / id = 4.2933 V / 1.8074 mA = 2.38 kOhms (these are the experimental values i obtained)?

Comment: If I ignore ro in the pi-model, I obtain a gain of -1.60 . Is this the correct gain?

Comment: The small-signal output resistance of the FET is ro=d(Vds)/d(Id). But this resistance should be listed in the data sheet.

Comment: Without bypassing the source resistor the gain is G=-3.2k/(2k+1k)=-1.066 (assuming gm=0.5mS and ignoring ro).

Comment: Right. And with the capacitor, it is -1.60 (if we ignore ro) which is greater than -1.07 without the capacitor. Does this make sense? I'm not sure about by answer because when I performed this experiment I obtained an output voltage of 2.70V when a 108 mV AC signal was applied, which is a gain of about ~25.

Comment: Yes , -1.6 is corect assuming gm=0.5mS and RD||Rload=3.3k. Perhaps the transconductance gm was larger in your experiment? By the way- up to now we didn`t consider the series resistor at the input (10k). We have a voltage division between 10k and the bias voltage divider.